# insert multiple ids from a department

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am creating a web form on asp.net that will allow the end user to assign multiple users bassed on a selected department to a quiz..

the database is mysql database since I use joomla

```
the tables on mysql are:

jos_users_quizzes with the following columns:
id
quiz_id
user_id

I have a second is called called  jos_users with this columns

id
name
username
department
```

the user_id on first table is going to be euqal to the id of second table jos_users

so quiz_id = id (jos_users)

How can build a query to multiple insert the ids of a selected department into the jos_users_quizzes table... IN ONE CLICK, I have a dropdownlist for the quiz ids and one for the userids , departments

I need to select all user ids from selected department and insert those id into the user_quizzes table.

Code from and ASP.NET form to insert ....

```
 private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=localhost;database=db_dhruniversity;uid=root;pwd=;";
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);

        try
        {

            conn.Open();


            string quizidselected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string deptselected = ListBox2.SelectedValue;
           // OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile  WHERE department = ' " + deptselected + " '");             
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {

            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }

        finally
        {

            conn.Close();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run:

```
Insert into jos_users_quizzes(quiz_id, user_id) select (your_quiz_id, user_id) from   jos_users where department='selectd_depatment'
```

Comment: this are the two queries the first one commented  wont insert.....`// OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile  WHERE department = ' " + deptselected + " '"); 
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile "); `

Comment: when i use the commented query it doesnt insert anyting , no errors

Comment: the table I am inserting on, doesnt have a field for department the where should be based on the select query  , meabe I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, this table shouldn't contain this field. It is used for selecting from table jos_users

Comment: What is the table dhruprofile? You didn't provide a table scheme of this one.

Comment: this one gives me error ,, ` OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT (uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile  WHERE department = ' " + deptselected + " ') "); `

Comment: Could you provide results of query SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile WHERE department = ' " + deptselected + " '"; Maybe you haven't got users in this dept.

Comment: You have got redundant braces near select. Try to use OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id) SELECT uid, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM dhruprofile WHERE department = ' " + deptselected + " ' ");

Comment: how can i send you the screenshots?

Comment: Could you run final query INSERT...SELECT directly in db and check error from command line?

Comment: this works,    on mysql directly, if I specify one of the existing departments.,,,,,   INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id) 
    SELECT uid, '5' FROM dhruprofile WHERE department = 'IT'

Comment: the department selection is on a listbox control ins asp.net page,..  `<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataTextField="department" DataValueField="department" Height="391px" 
            Width="241px"></asp:ListBox>`

Comment: Could you print query which is formed in your script? Anyway I have provided a solution for initial question and now it's necessary to fix C# code. You can vote for answer and if you couldn't find solution tonight we can proceed tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe you send id not string? How do you form control? I mean key=>value

Comment: <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataTextField="department" DataValueField="department" Height="391px" 
            Width="241px"></asp:ListBox>

Comment: I don't know how to do in php but you generate exception with message=your query. You will look this message on display than put down this one in this chat. So I should go to bed. It's very late. We can proceed tomorrow if you couldn't resolve this problem now. Good luck!